# Python behave running from python2.7 rather than python3.4

Tags: python-behave

When I run behave it seems to run from python2.7 and fails to find selenium, which is installed for python3.4. Do I need to configure behave to run python3.4 somewhere - I can see nothing on the [behave site](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/behave.html#configuration-files), or elsewhere. There are posts about using behave with python 3.4, so it is possible.

Here is what I see:

```
$ behave 
...
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/behave/runner.py", line 304, in exec_file
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "features/steps/home_page.py", line 2, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named selenium
```

I have `PYTHONPATH` pointing to python 3.4/dist-packages:

```
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
$ ls /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium
common  __init__.py  __pycache__  selenium.py  webdriver
```

I have behave installed in both `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.X/dist-packages` where X.X is 2.7 and 3.4

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install behave for Python 3.x and Python 2.7 each installation will install the script that starts Behave at the `/usr/local/bin/behave` location. **Whichever is installed last will win the conflict** because it will overwrite the other's file. (The files that go in `/usr/local/lib/python<version>/dist-packages` will be fine because `<version>` is different in each case.)

One way to fix this is to settle on installing Behave only on Python 3. Uninstall the Python 2.7 version and reinstall the Python 3 version, and it should work.

If you do need both versions for different projects then you should use `virtualenv` to create Python installations for the various projects you are working on. This is what I've settled on for my own projects.

Comment: Thanks Louis, you pointed me at the answer. I had tried uninstalling and re-installing with pip and pip3 - although there is some confusion when pip thinks behave is already installed or uninstalled with the other version. So first I just edited the shebang in the `

Comment: Thanks Louis, you pointed me at the answer. I had tried uninstalling and re-installing with pip and pip3 - although there was confusion when pip thinks behave is already installed or uninstalled with the other version (not saying who was confused, pip or me). So first I just edited the shebang in `/usr/local/bin/behave` to run python3 instead of python, which did the trick. Later I got the uninstall/install sequence to work and got to the same change. So you could probably just edit the shebang in `behave` and fix the problem. Thanks so much.